# How to send image from back-end in your web push notifications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, web-push

I am using web-push library to send push notification using node server. For now, I am only able to send title from the back-end. Is there any way to send image from the back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example function that send a notification with image:

```
function sendPushNotification(req, res) {
  const subscriptionId = req.params.id;
  const pushSubscription = subscriptions[subscriptionId];
  webpush
    .sendNotification(
      pushSubscription,
      JSON.stringify({
        title: "your title",
        text: "your text",
        image: "path/to/image.jpg",
        tag: "new...",
        url: "/your-url.html"
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  res.status(202).json({});
}
```

this is from Lorenzo Spyna that explains how do it in this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/an-introduction-to-web-push-notifications-a701783917ce) and you can see all code in [this project](https://github.com/Spyna/push-notification-demo) of github